# flutter Android license status unknown. (command `ver` returned Windows)

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, flutter-doctor, windowsversion

An error occurred that cannot be corrected..
Even though I typed “flutter doctor --android-licenses”, nothing works.
but, [x] Android license status unknown error

[error image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nke6m.png)

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.

searching.. help... what..

Comment: there is the link under Anroid toolchain error. You should check it first and follow the instructions